# cin.getline goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to get a string with spaces using the `cin.getline()` function but when I do it my program loops endlessly.

I added the `'\n'` but it won't work.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "HealthClub.h"

void main()
{
    int i, ans=0;
    char tname[20] = { 0 }, dname[20] = { 0 };
    HealthClub newhc;
    cout << "please enter the new trainer`s name:" << endl;
    cin.getline(tname, 20, '\n');
    newhc.addTrainer(tname);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post your code as images.  Please [edit] your question with an [mcve]

Comment: Your code doesn't have a loop at all. Are you quite sure that it *goes to infinity loop*?

Comment: sorry, i meant that it just print me "please enter the new trainer`s name:" again and again.

Comment: Can you please show us how `tname` is defined? And please post the whole loop or even better a MCVE.

Comment: @HadarKrispin I highly doubt that. Are you sure that's all of your code?

Comment: sure, tname is : char tname[20] = { 0 }; and what is MCVE? im new here.. :)

Comment: @user2079303 i`ll send the whole code right now.. :)

Comment: @HadarKrispin please add the code as code inside your question, not as image.

Comment: @HadarKrispin don't send your whole code. Read the link that NathanOliver provided. Then send your *whole* mcve.

Comment: @user2079303 i changed it... thank you :)

Comment: @SimonKraemer can you help me please?

Comment: @HadarKrispin you just have stripped of the relevant part of your code. Before doing that, please compile and run, to check, that the remaining code still shows the described behavior..

Answer (score 0):

```
while (ans != 7)
{
    cin >> ans;
    switch (ans)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "please enter the new trainer`s name:" << endl;
            cin.getline(tname, 20, '\n');
            newhc.addTrainer(tname);
        }
        break;
    // ...
```

You never change `ans` in this case block. `ans` will still be 1 afterwards, the while loop just starts over and goes into the first statement again.

It does not have anything to do with `getline()`.

Comment: The relevant part is caused by the `getline()`. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

The first is already described by `cdonat`. Think about what happens when you enter a `1`.

1. `ans` is 1.
2. The `case 1` part is executed.
3. The `while` condition is checked.
4. The loop is executed again as ans is `1`

Maybe this is even desired behaviour - I don't know.

You second problem is indead the `getline`. `getline` doesn't remove the linebreak from the input stream.
This remaining linebreak is used as trigger when you call `cin >> ans;`.

Depending on the used C++ version the `cin>>` doesn't change the value it writes to when the input is invalid.

As your input stream is a single linebreak this constantly passes an empty string to `ans`. So `ans` will never change away from `1`.

The same behaviour also causes `getline` to return an empty string directly.

You need to clear the input stream after you called `getline` to remove/ignore the remaining data.
Add a call to `cin.ignore();` after your `cin.getline()` like this

```
cin.getline(tname, 20, '\n');
cin.ignore();
```